# Why cannot I cast com object in c#?

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

The source code:

```
   IMoniker moniker;
    int hresult = NativeMethods.CreateFileMoniker(kFileName, out moniker);
    IBindCtx pbc;
    NativeMethods.CreateBindCtx(0, out pbc);
    Object obj;
    Guid guid = new Guid();
    guid = typeof(GraphicsLibrary.IPolyline).GUID;
    moniker.BindToObject(pbc, null, guid, out obj);
    GraphicsLibrary.IPolyline pl = (GraphicsLibrary.IPolyline)obj;
    GraphicsLibrary.PolylineObjClass o = (GraphicsLibrary.PolylineObjClass)pl;
    foreach (GraphicsLibrary.PolyPoint ptt in o.Points)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(String.Format("point ({0}, {1})", ptt.x, ptt.y));
    }
    return 0;
```

Exception on `GraphicsLibrary.PolylineObjClass o = (GraphicsLibrary.PolylineObjClass)pl;`

Detail:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   DotNetClient.exe but was not handled in user code

But I have implemented the IProvideClassInfo interface and did register the typelib.

Why cannot I cast the object?

PS: full source code, please refer https://github.com/Jichao/comtut/tree/master/monikers/FileMoniker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object is an implementation of IPolyline and do not comes from any superclass of PolylineObjClass or PolylineObjClass itself.

- `A` implements `IPolyline`
- `B` implements `IPolyline`
- `myFirstObj = new B();`
- `mySecondObj = (A) myFirstObj;` <= Failure, because `B` might implements other methods or properties `A` doesn't, so impossible to cast
- `mySecondObj = (IPolyline) myFirstObj;` <= work, you are limited the cast to the same scope of methods.